# .NET WebChannelFactory service proxy leaves connection open, even though it is disposed

Tags: .net, wcf, dispose

I have the following code:

```
using (var fact = new WebChannelFactory<IService<Message>>(binding,
              commsSettings.MessageEndPoint()))
{
    using (IDisposable channel = (IDisposable)fact.CreateChannel())
    {
         service = (IService<Message>)channel;
         service.Create(AlertMessage);
         ((IClientChannel)channel).Close();
    }
    fact.Close();
}
```

Even though I am disposing the WebChannelFactory and the Channel itself, they are leaving connections open. I know this because in a performance test, the calls start timing out at the 10th call, and if I do netstat -a at the command line I can see a whole bunch of sockets open between my local machine and itself on port 80.

How can I make the proxy close its socket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was server-side. We had a leak of a signal-R client per service instance, which used up the available sockets.

When that happened, clients could no longer connect.

Hint for anyone else debugging something similar: Look at your server and see if it is not constructing some kind of WCF client and not cleaning them up. The symptom that gave it away was that the sockets seen with netstat -a still remained in an ESTABLISHED state after the client process had been terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the way Microsoft implemented service proxies (`IClientChannel` and its inheritors) in WCF allows exceptions to occur in the Close/Dispose methods. When this happens, you must call the Abort method to release the unmanaged resources (TCP sockets in your case). Look at this [brief blog post](http://omaralzabir.com/do-not-use-using-in-wcf-client/) on this issue and implement the dispose pattern it describes  instead of the `using` statement.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am not seeing any exceptions though, could they be silent somehow ?

Comment: They could be silent if they occur during the "finally" phase of the `using` statement. If you're familiar with WinDbg, try taking a memory dump when you see the TCP socket leaks and see how they're being held in memory. That might give you a clue to instance reference issue and the .NET garbage collector processing.

Comment: I found the issue, it ended up having nothing to do with the proxies. We were leaking SignalR clients in the service call on the server side, which used up a socket each. Once the limit of WCF sockets was reached, clients could not connect